# Characteres de Textarea quebra linha ao submeter ao banco de dados

Tags: php, html, html-select

Tenho um formulário com um campo `SELECT` e ao submeter o texto no banco de dados, ele quebra linha, até copiei e colei direto do registro da tabela no bloco de notas e está mesmo quebrado, no HTML o `SELECT` está asssim:

```
<textarea id="descricao" name="descricao" wrap="physical" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Insira a descrição relacionada..." rows="22" draggable="true"></select>
```

Antes de ser inserido na base de dados, o valor de `TEXTAREA` passa por uma validação:

```
<?php
if( !function_exists('filtra_var') ){
    function filtra_var($var) {
        $var = trim($var);
        $var = strip_tags($var);
        $var = addslashes($var);
        return $var;
    }
}

$descricao = $_POST['desricao']
$desricao = filtra_var( $descricao );

/* INSERT IN DB */
?>
```

O texto abaixo insiro ele assim, sem quebra:

> What is Lorem Ipsum?
>
> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
>   since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
>   scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

Recuperando o registro da tabela com PHP:

```
<?php
$descricao = stripslashes( $row['descricao'] ); // $row == mysqli_fetch_array( $query_sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 

$descricao = nl2br ( $descricao );

echo $descricao;
?>
```

O texto retornado na tela fica quebrado:

> What is Lorem Ipsum?
>
> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
>
> and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
>
> industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
>
> when an unknown printer took a galley of type
>
> and  scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

Pois bem, não existe quebra de linha, ou seja, `<br>`, além de "What is Lorem Ipsum?", e o texto é quebrado, deveria estar no banco de dados assim:

> What is Lorem Ipsum?
>
> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing 
>   and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the 
>   industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
>   when an unknown printer took a galley of type
>   and  scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

Comment: A função [nl2br](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) adiciona um `<br>` antes de todas as quebras de linha, ou seja, sua string contém quebras de linha sim. É importante lembrar que o HTML considera uma quebra de linha apenas como um whitespace, em teoria um espaço e um `\n` são renderizados da mesma forma (dependendo da tag onde é renderizado, ver [docs da propriedade CSS `whitespace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space))

Comment: Mas no banco de dados já insere quebrada. Eu sei da importância, por isso usei, mas está anormal o comportamento.

Comment: Se no banco de dados já insere quebrado é porque o `textarea` recebeu quebra de linha. Seu próprio exemplo (a parte em amarelo) tem quebras de linha.

Comment: Não sr. te garanto que não, colei do bloco de notas e verifiquei antes, fiz N testes.

Comment: Então não tenho informação o suficiente pra ajudar. Tenta colar [nesse fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d0hrgw6s/16/) e vê se ele acusa alguma quebra de linha.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema, incrementei o código que valida o valor antes de ser inserido no banco de dados.

```
<?php
if( !function_exists('filtra_var') ){
    function filtra_var($var) {
        $var = trim($var);
        $var = strip_tags($var);
        $var = addslashes($var);
        return $var;
    }
}

$descricao = $_POST['desricao']
$desricao = filtra_var( $descricao );
$descricao = nl2br( $descricao, false );

/* INSERT IN DB */
?>
```

Sendo assim o texto é enviado com a quebra de linha e no lugar de `\n` fica inserido no banco o `<br>`.

E na impressão do valor ficou assim:

```
<?php
$descricao = stripslashes( $row['descricao'] ); // $row == mysqli_fetch_array( $query_sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 

$descricao = stripslashes( $descricao );

echo $descricao;
?>
```